# How to compose a variable name in one line, as part of struct call?

Tags: c, if-statement, struct, concatenation, conditional-operator

I have NO idea if what i'm trying to accomplish is doable at all. I'm pretty new to C.

I have a struct that contains a pointer to another struct, that contains yet another pointer to another struct.
The last struct contains two pointers to structs called "leadingToCw" and "leadingToCcW". I also have a global String variable dir which can change from Cw to Ccw at any point in time. It looks someting like this:

```
#define concat(a,b) a##b
String dir = "Ccw"; // or "Cw"

struct Intersection {
    struct Sector *incoming;
}

struct Sector {
    struct Sector *leadingToCcw;
    struct Sector *leadingToCw;
};
```

Now the thing i want to is call the leadingToCcw or leadingToCw depending on the "dir" string, so that the output would look like this:

```
Intersection->incoming->leadingToCcw
```

I've tried something like this:

```
Intersection->incoming->(dir == "Ccw" ? concat(leadingTo, Ccw) : concat(leadingTo, Cw))
```

but i get this error:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before '(' token
```

I don't know if it's worth mentioning but it is for an Arduino project :-)
I hope someone can help me, or kick me in the butt and tell me that it is not feasible!

Comment: There's no `String` in C, it's in C++. Please amend the tags accordingly.

Comment: Arduino is programmed in C++, not C.

Comment: @montonero There's no `String` in C++ either.

Comment: @interjay My point was about incorrect tags, not about if `String` is a part of C++ standards. Obviously that the string comparison used by OP isn't possible in C but quite legal in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't use a usual condition?

```
dir == "Ccw"? Intersection->incoming->leadingToCcw : Intersection->incoming->leadingToCw
```

Comment: We don't compare strings like that.

Comment: Yes, that is a very very good question. Especially because it works... Thanks man!

Comment: @Mazhar if by "we" you mean "we, C developers", then you're totally correct. But unfortunately this question is not about C.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like `String` in the C. You can use `char *` instead like below

```
char *dir = "Ccw";

if (strcmp(dir, "Ccw") == 0)
{
// Do whatever you want to do with Intersection->incoming->leadingToCcw
}
else if (strcmp(dir, "Cw") == 0)
{
// Do whatever you want to do with Intersection->incoming->leadingToCw
}
```